# How would you translate "The Snow Queen" into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, adjective

"The Snow Queen" here being the Anderson's personage.
*Regina Nix*, *Regina Nivis*, *Regina Nivea*, *Regina Nivosa*?
Which is closer to the original meaning? (And what is it, at last?)
To me, it's not *the queen of snow*, yet not *the snowy queen* either. Something in between…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Regina Nix* Apposition, although not wrong, isn't the most idiomatic way of saying it.

*Regina Nivis* sounds better if she rules the snow somehow. We have, of course, *Regina caeli* 'Queen of Heaven' as a comparison here.

*Regina Nivea* sounds quite good, although it also has the 'Snowy Queen' feel to it.

*Regina Nivosa* feels like she is stuffed with snow or fully created of snow.

I will not commit to any translation because it depends on the context.

Comment: The apposition would indicate that the queen *is* snow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Actually, I want to name so a new species of a kind of a worm, new to science, being described from Svalbard :) With a clear allusion to Andersen.

Comment: What about *Regina Nivalis*?